# What does "norms less than $\delta$" refers to in the context of Riemann sum?

Tags: real-analysis

> What does "norms less than $\delta$" refers to in the context of Riemann sum?

Given this problem "Prove if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ exists, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta >0 $ such that $|\sigma_1 -\sigma_2|<\epsilon$,  if $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are Riemann sums of $f$ over partitions P$_1$ and P$_2$ of $[a,b] $ with **norms** less than $\delta$."

I am trying to understand this problem that I posted [Prove that if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ exists, $\delta >0 $ such that $|\sigma_1 -\sigma_2|<\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371866/prove-that-if-int-ab-fx-exists-delta-0-such-that-sigma-1-si) ), I did receive one answer but I am not understanding the how and the why of his argumentation leads to the conclusion that "**the norms is less than $\delta$**" (sub-question "norms" why plural?). What should be understood from by "**the norms is less than $\delta$**"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if $\int_{a}^{b} f(x)$ exists, $\delta &gt;0 $ such that $|\sigma_1 -\sigma_2|&lt;\epsilon$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371866/prove-that-if-int-ab-fx-exists-delta-0-such-that-sigma-1-si)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plural concerns the two subdivisions or partitions $P_1$ and $P_2$.

if $P=(x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n) $ is a subdivision of $[a,b] $ then what you call norm of $P $ is

$$\|P\|=\max_{0\le i\le n-1}\{x_{i+1}-x_i\} $$

Answer (score -3):

Before this there should be a definition of the "[norm of a partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval#Norm_of_a_partition)". The norms being referred to here are the norm of $P_1$ and the norm of $P_2$; both are less than $\delta $.

Comment: I would be happy to address any issues with my answer. If someone would prefer not to comment publicly, I can be reached privately as well (instructions are in my profile).