# Prove that $f$ is not integrable over $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that there is an $M>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there are Riemann sums $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ over a partition P of $[a,b]$ with $||P||<\delta$ such that $|\sigma_1 - \sigma_2| \geq M$. Prove that $f$ is not integrable over [a,b].

Given that for $M>0$,  we have
$$|\sigma_1 - \sigma_2| \geq M$$ 
$$|\sigma_1 -L + L - \sigma_2| \geq M$$
applying the triangle inequality:
$$|\sigma_1 -L| + |L - \sigma_2| \geq |\sigma_1 - \sigma_2| \geq M$$
$$|\sigma_1 -L| + |\sigma_2-L| \geq M$$

It shows that there exists at least one of the quantity unbounded (let $\sigma_1$ be considered) 
It follows that for at least one $\epsilon$, we have 
$$|\sigma_1 -L|>\epsilon$$
This contradict the definition of $L$ defined as the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$, $L=\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx$ as the unique Riemann integral of $f$, where $\forall$P of $[a,b]$: $$\left|\sigma_1 - \int_{a}^{b} f(x)\, dx\right|<\epsilon$$
Therefore $f$ is not integrable over $[a,b]$.

I would like to know if my proof is correctly done but also if there is anything to be added and or to be rectified.
Much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what $L$ is. It comes out of nowhere.

Comment: This is the contrapositive of [the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2371866/prove-that-if-int-ab-fx-exists-delta-0-such-that-sigma-1-si/2371879?noredirect=1#comment4889252_2371879) you asked yesterday.

Comment: Yes it is. checking if I understood your proof you showed yesterday. thx again.