# Definition of Riemann-Stieltjes Integral (boundedness of integrated function)

Tags: integration, definition, stieltjes-integral

**Question**:

Not all integrable functions are bounded, yet in the book I am studying, integration is defined with respect to bounded functions. Why is this?

**Background**:

I have been studying the Riemann-Stieltjes integral in *Foundations of Mathematical Analysis* by Richard Johnsonbaugh.

He gives the following **definition** for the Riemann-Stieltjes integral:

> Let $f$ and $\alpha$ be bounded functions on $[a,b]$. We say that $f$
>   is *Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $\alpha$ on $[a,b]$*,
>   and write $f \in \mathscr{R}_{\alpha} [a,b]$, if there exists a number
>   $I$ having the property that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a
>   partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that if $P^*$ is a refinement of $P$,
>   then $$|S(f,P^*,T)-I|<\epsilon$$ for any points $T$.

Comment: That definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral can never be satisfied if $f$ is unbounded.  This is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311162/148510).  A function might be Lebesgue integrable or improperly Riemann integrable, but never Riemann integrable if it is unbounded.  You need the broader theory of integration to handle unbounded functions and/or unbounded intervals

Comment: RRL to the rescue again! I see now that my question is a duplicate, so I'll leave it to the mods to delete or not.